# Refresh UITableViewController from another thread

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have back end that send notification messages to my app to notify users to download new data set. When user receives notification, the alert box is created in push notification thread, and asks users to accept or refuse data set download. If user accepts download, it downloads the data in async. What I want to do is, I want to refresh the table view once the download is complete. But I'm on different thread and I don't know how to update the `Tableview` from that thread. How do I do that?

```
func downloadContent(key: String, pinOnCompletion: Bool) {

        let manager = AWSUserFileManager.defaultUserFileManager()
        let content = manager.contentWithKey(self.prefix + key)

        content.downloadWithDownloadType(
            .IfNewerExists,
            pinOnCompletion: pinOnCompletion,
            progressBlock: {[weak self](content: AWSContent?, progress: NSProgress?) -> Void in
                guard self != nil else { return }
                /* Show progress in UI. */
            },
            completionHandler: {[weak self](content: AWSContent?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                guard self != nil else { return }
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed to download a content from a server. \(error)")
                    return
                }
                if let fileData = data {
                    // Saves Data to core data here
                    //  Update the tableViewController

                }
                print("Object download complete.")
            })
    }
```

**Update-1**
This is not duplicate post. The suggested duplicate post asked how to update `Tableviewcontroller` from async task inside `Tableviewcontroller` class. My question is about updating `Tableviewcontroller` from another thread from different class.

**Update-2**
Just to clarify, this download function inside download manager class is invoked from a class that implements `AmazonPushNotificationManager`. It gets called when push notification is received. So I'm not on the UI thread anymore when I invoke download. I'm on pushnotification thread. If I pass completion handler, that'd be from pushnotification thread, not from UI. And I have two views (one is `Tableview` and the other is `UIViewController`). User could be on either one when push notification is received. So I should not be reloading table data if user is on `UIViewController`. I hope that does not sound confusing.

Comment: It was the same. The other question was about updating the table on the main thread from a background thread. That is the same thing you are asking.

Comment: @rmaddy I fail to see it as duplicate. I'm not on UI thread anymore when I initiate download. Download is invoked from push notification delegate. It is a background thread of push notification delegate, not of UI thread.

Comment: That's why it is a duplicate. The other question was doing the same thing - running some code on a background thread and needing to update the UI on the main thread. The answers showed you how to update the table on the main thread from a background thread. That's just what you need to do.

Comment: @rmaddy :I'm confuse.The only thing my post and that one shares is updating UI from another thread.For that post, he initates the download from UI thread, and wanted to refresh UI from that thread.IMO, It's much simpler, and if I were in that scenario, I could get away with Whakkee solution bcoz I'd still be inside UI scope and could call self.tableView.But in my situation, I have no access to tableView anymore because I'm inside pushNotification delegate scope. In fact, I should be checking before refreshing becoz I have more than one view and user maybe on the view that does not list data.

Comment: @user30646, Please use custom Delegate(Protocol) i think may be work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't update your UI from a background thread, instead, you switch back to the main thread, like this:

**Swift 2:**

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

or...

**Swift 3**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Because download thread is inside different class. Not inside TableViewController class.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you **don't** update UI objects like table view controllers from a background thread. That is explicitly forbidden.

What you want to do is to write a function in your download manager class (if that's what the class is) that takes a completion handler. Write your downloadContent function so it invokes the completion handler once the download is complete. I have a sample project on Github called [**Async_demo**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/Async_demo) (link) that demonstrates exactly this technique. (This project is written in Swift 3. At this point you should be doing new development in Swift 3. Why are you asking about Swift 2 now that Swift 3 has been released?)

The key function is this:

```
  /**
   This function demonstrates handling an async task.
   - Parameter url The url to download
   - Parameter completion: A completion handler to execute once the download is finished
   */


func downloadFileAtURL(_ url: URL, completion: @escaping DataClosure) {

  //We create a URLRequest that does not allow caching so you can see the download take place
  let request = URLRequest(url: url,
                           cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
                           timeoutInterval: 30.0)
  let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
    //------------------------------------------
    //This is the completion handler, which runs LATER,
    //after downloadFileAtURL has returned.
    data, response, error in

    //Perform the completion handler on the main thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
      //Call the copmletion handler that was passed to us
      completion(data, error)
    }
    //------------------------------------------
  }
  dataTask.resume()

  //When we get here the data task will NOT have completed yet!
}
```

}

---

Comment: Why did you reopen? It was the same as what I closed it for. The OP wants to reload the table on the main thread from the background. That is what the other question asked and answered. It's the same as your answer.

Comment: @rmaddy, It was clear to me that the OP doesn't understand what it means to do UI calls in a completion handler wrapped in a GCD call to the main thread. The other thread you referenced did not explain how to handle doing work on a background thread and then sending UI updates to the main thread, and I decided it could use a clear explanation.

Comment: I was using Swift 3 until I decided to integrate with AmazonMobileClient. It does not support Swift 3. Anyway, I'm still new to Swift, and I'm confuse about your answer. So this download function inside download manager class is invoked from a class that implements AmazonPushNotificationManager. It gets called when push notification is received. So I'm not on the main thread anymore when I invoke download. I'm on pushnotification thread. I updated my post to clarify.